# ERROR Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'undefined'

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

I am trying to access user location when they click on a button but I keep getting an error,

ERROR Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'undefined'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions. i went through react redux and found out about react redux handling asynchronous function, so I went to add thunk on my project store but am still getting tesame error

here is my code

//store.js file

```
import { userSlice } from './slices/userSlice';
import { homeSlice } from './slices/HomeSlice';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
// import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: userSlice.reducer,
    home: homeSlice.reducer,
});

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(thunk),
});

export default store;
```

//userslice.js

```
const initialState = {
    userLocation: null,
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        
        setUserLocation: (state, action) => {
            state.userLocation = action.payload
        },
    },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { setUserLocation,} = userSlice.actions

export const selectUserLocation = (state) => state.user.userLocation

export default userSlice.reducer
```

```
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectSearchMode } from '../slices/HomeSlice';
import { selectUserLocation, setUserLocation } from '../slices/userSlice';
import FlatButton from '../component/FlatButton';
import SearchComponent from '../component/for_user/SearchComponent';
import tw from 'twrnc';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const LocationCheckerScreen = () => {
    const [locationPermission, setLocationPermission] = useState(false);
    const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState(null);
    const selectSearchMod = useSelector(selectSearchMode);
    const selectLocationChecker = useSelector(selectUserLocation);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleLocation = (location) => {
        if (location === null || location === undefined) {
            dispatch(setUserLocation({ location: null }));
        } else {
            dispatch(setUserLocation({ location }));
        }
    };

    const setCurrentLocation = async () => {
        try {
            let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();

            if (status !== 'granted') {
                console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
                return;
            }

            let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
            if (location){
                setUserLocation(location)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error occurred while getting location:', error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentLocation();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (userLocation && userLocation !== "later") {
            handleLocation(userLocation);
        }
    }, [userLocation]); 

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={tw`px-4 flex-1 pb-4`}>
            {selectLocationChecker === null ? (
                <View style={tw`px-4 justify-center`}>
                    <View style={tw`my-6`}>
                        <Text style={tw`text-xl mb-3 font-semibold text-center`}>Where is your present location?</Text>
                        <Text style={tw`text-[14px] text-center`}>
                            Let us help the employer easily find your location and ensure a smooth and efficient process in locating
                            you.
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={tw`px-5 mt-3`}>
                        <FlatButton text="Set location automatically" onPress={() => setCurrentLocation()} />
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={tw`flex-row justify-center p-[6px] mt-3 border-2 border-gray-500 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-300`}
                            onPress={() => handleLocation('later')}
                        >
                            <Text style={tw`text-lg font-semibold`}>Set later</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            ) : (
                <View style={tw`px-6 flex-1`}>
                    <SearchComponent />
                </View>
            )}
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default LocationCheckerScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: You have declared some local state with the same `setUserLocation` setter function as the imported `setUserLocation` action creator function, and this is the function used in local scope. Rename one or the other, or both, to be different. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that because your state setter is the same name as the action. this is your action

```
export const { setUserLocation,} = userSlice.actions
```

inside `LocationCheckerScreen` you have this `useState`

```
const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState(null);
```

when you dispatch, i think you are dispatching useState setter

```
if (location === null || location === undefined) {
        dispatch(setUserLocation({ location: null }));
```

change the name of the useState setter